# Status 500 Error while creating mapping on an index in Elasticsearch cluster

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using Elasticsearch 1.1 on OpenJDK Java 1.7.0(iced tea) on all the nodes of the cluster

While executing the following command:

```
PUT http://my_machine:9200/index_name
{ 
  "mappings":
  {
      "index_type" : 
      {
          "properties" : 
          {
              "file" : { "type" : "attachment" }
          }
      }
  }
}
```

I get the following response json:

```
{
error: "RemoteTransportException[Failed to deserialize exception response from stream]; nested: TransportSerializationException[Failed to deserialize exception response from stream]; nested: StreamCorruptedException[unexpected end of block data]; "
status: 500
}
```

Further, normal GET/PUT/POST requests are working well if the mapping header is not included. e.g.

```
PUT http://my_machine:9200/index_name
```

works well and returns

```
{"acknowledged":true}
```

Can anyone explain the reason and suggest possible solutions?

Comment: Is the minor version of java same across nodes ? what client are you using for the commands ? what is the version of attachment plugin across nodes :  You could use this to query curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/_cluster/stats?pretty=1'

Comment: I found the problem. The attachment plugin I downloaded was not compatible with ES 1.1.